# In Redux if all reducers are called when an action fires, then what's preventing possible naming conflict among actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Each big components get its own list of actions. Separation of files implies that they are isolate actions. But from my understanding if a type of an action matches the type of another action in completely separate file meant for different reducer will still cause problem.

EDIT:

if i have two sections in the app. One has reducer for action SET_SCROLL, and other section has that too. If i update scroll position in section 2, by firing SET_SCROLL. This would cause section 1's state to change. Now imagine 100s of actions, how do you prevent naming conflicts? I understand in redux you can't associate set of actions with a certain reducers.

Comment: Can you give an example? It's hard to tell what the problem is you're asking about.

Comment: Why do you think it may be a problem for reducer? He will just fire twice ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: @MuhammadUmer please [edit] your question to include the example, don't just put it in a comment.

Comment: You name your actions properly via namespacing using a convention that makes sense for your project, and when calling actions, using constants. TL;DR: there's nothing at the code level to prevent name collisions.

Comment: can you suggest a common convention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is why you should be careful when defining action types.  The ["Reusing Reducer Logic" docs page](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) gives examples of how this can be a problem when you want to reuse a given reducer in more than one place, and shows some ways around that.

We specifically recommend [defining action types as `"domain/someAction"`](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#write-action-types-as-domain-eventname) to help avoid clashes.

Note that [it's also possible (and recommended) to have many different parts of the reducer logic all independently respond to the same dispatched action](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#allow-many-reducers-to-respond-to-the-same-action)